# jQuery foggy plugin with .click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed (so far) to create this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mecko/4n1u5krd/8/).
What I want to do other than that is reversing the [foggy plugin](http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/) process using the same button that trigger the whole process with a little help from `foggy(false);`
As you can see, I managed to trigger `.foggy` on `.click` but I can't reverse it yet

**Solution**: 
I noticed that Foggy plugin isn't dynamic enough to remove the attribute that it created, it only removes `style=""` attr on load.
While I am still beginner of JavaScrpit I couldn't edit it to fit my needs, so I decided to use different method to get the main `div class="bcontainer"` blurry, its simple but effective. since I used `.toggleClass` with `.click` I used it to add another `class="backgroundblur"` to `div class="bcontainer"`  than I used pure css3 -webkit-filter: blur(2px); to get things done,
and that is how I did it

Comment: You would need to use that library like it is written....` $('.your-selector').foggy(false);` It is not as simple as toggling a class.

Comment: I am aware of .foggy(false); but I don't know how to use it properly. That is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: You call that line when you want to remove it.

Comment: Yes, But how to link it with the same trigger that fires it?